# How to reverse a string in python and the reversal should contain the reversal case letters

Tags: python

**Question:**
I'm new to Python and trying to reverse a string. What's the simplest way to achieve this? I've seen a few methods online, but I'm not sure which one is the most straightforward and commonly used. Could someone provide a clear example of how to reverse a string in Python?

i was trying to reverse a string like "Hello world" to get output "DLROW OLLEh"

Comment: Show what you tried, even if it didn't work, so we can help you to improve it. Which methods have you researched, why do you think they're not straightforward enough? Obviously there's no _commonly used_ method to reverse a string and the case, this is not the kind of problem people face in real-life problems. Since you are just learning python, you may want to read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. If you "have seen a few methods online", then there is no longer a suitable question for that topic; it is your responsibility to judge what is "most straightforward", and what is "commonly used" is irrelevant (especially since reversing a string is *rarely a meaningful task in real-world code* but instead the sort of thing that gets assigned for homework in order to test your understanding). If the examples you already found were not "clear", there's no way we can help without knowing **why**.

Comment: Aside from that, the task of swapping the case of the letters is **completely separate from and unrelated to** reversing the string, and solving the overall problem means taking both steps - there's no way around that; which makes this two completely different questions. We require one question per post.

Answer (score -1):

```
original_string = "Hello world"
reversed_string = ''.join([char.upper() if char.islower() else char.lower() for char in original_string])[::-1]

print(reversed_string)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

original_string = "Hello world"
reversed_string = original_string[::-1]

print(reversed_string)

Comment: How is this swapping the font case?